# Is there a resource that shows all uses of a Tanach verse in the Talmud?

Tags: product-recommendation, talmud-gemara, tanach

Is there a website or book that can tell me all the places in *Shas* where a certain *pasuk* is mentioned or referenced?

(Preferably website, and preferably can show places in Midrash, too.)

Comment: *Toldos Aharon* and *Torah T'mimah* come to mind. See also [this article](http://shesileizeisim.blogspot.com/2011/12/talmudic-indexes.html) by [LazerA](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/1216/lazera).

Comment: It's probably vastly incomplete (especially for links to resources other than the _Talmud Bavli_), but the Hebrew Wikisource has for every verse a page with links to other places in Wikisource that mention the verse (and link back to it's page). For an example, see [the page for Devarim 33:4](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/קטגוריה:דברים_לג_ד).

Comment: The Art Scroll gemaras have indexes in the back for that particular volume.  It has long been my hope that Art Scroll would combine their indexes into a separate volume.

Comment: Related http://blog.sefaria.org/2015/05/18/how-much-of-tanach-is-in-the-talmud/

Answer (score 18):

I think the most complete indexing book of that kind is 
תורה הכתובה והמסורה
by אהרן הימן. 
It's published by דביר in three volumes.

It goes through the whole Bible verse by verse, giving for each verse a list of locations in Talmud and Midrash where the verse is mentioned in some way.

It's available on HebrewBooks:
[vol 1](http://hebrewbooks.org/39132) (torah)
[vol 2](http://hebrewbooks.org/39134) (nevi'im)
[vol 3](http://hebrewbooks.org/39133) (ketuvim)

Answer (score 10):

Other answers have offered modern, more complete resources. I'll stick to basics: many, many traditional prints of *Chumash* and of *Nach* include something called *[Tol'dos Aharon](http://hebrewbooks.org/45282)*, a work of the 16th century Italian [Aaron of Pesaro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aaron_of_Pesaro), which lists, for each phrase, every citation of that phrase in *Bavli* and a few other sources. Or almost every. (And if I'm not mistaken, it doesn't count duplicates: if the same passage of *g'mara* appears in two places, *TA* will point to one of them.)

Note when reading *TA* that a colon after a page number indicates the flip side; a period, the obverse.

Comment: An extremely good writing about _Toledot Aharon_ https://www.machonso.org/hamaayan/?gilayon=44&id=1324

Comment: In the linked Venice edition it seems that he listed all occurrences

Answer (score 7):

1. This [Sefaria website](http://www.sefaria.org/explore) might be helpful.
2. R. Yechiel Michel Stern has a sefer called התורה התמימה which is essentially a Torah Temimah on Nach. Five volumes are available on hebrewbooks.org: 
   [Yehoshua](http://hebrewbooks.org/50394), [Shoftim](http://hebrewbooks.org/50392), [Shmuel](http://hebrewbooks.org/50391), [Tehillim](http://hebrewbooks.org/50393), [Chamesh Megillot](http://hebrewbooks.org/50390).

Answer (score 5):

[Andrew Greene](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/432/andrew-m-greene) compiled [this index](http://cycle12.dafcast.net/tanach-bavli.pdf) using digital copies of Tanakh and Bavli from Mechon Mamre and a script or program that he wrote.  He explains:

> Each chapter which has at least one citation in the Bavli is listed in order.  Each masechta is only named once, followed by a list of daphim.

So this lists it by chapter, not by individual verse; the latter would likely be pretty unwieldy. This index is 14 pages, which, printed double-sided, tucks easily into a book or notebook.  (If you print it 2-up it'll of course be even more compact, but that gets pretty small.)

Comment: I tried to lure Andrew here so he could answer himself, but he sent me the link instead.

Comment: I was hoping for something I could search, but this is pretty handy.

Answer (score 2):

I think [HaMafteach](http://hamafteach.org/en/home) has a complete index of verses.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya.  In the future you might want to summarize a bit more about the sources you provide links to.  HaMafteach is a recent attempt to index by subject the Babylonian Talmud.  I bought it and was very disappointed, for one reason because it lacks the very index the OP is looking for, and also because it misses many lengthy discussions in the Talmud that should have shown up in the index and do not.  This, I suspect, is the major reason why Feldheim did not publish the Hebrew-only version that was promised. I think they discontinued HaMafteach, too.

Comment: My mistake. I had heard good things about it, but I guess it wasn't as great as I'd heard.

Answer (score 2):

Soncino press has an index to the Talmud which lists every chapter of the Tanakh and any Gemorah that quotes it.  I attached an image to show. [image]

Answer (score 1):

The Bar Ilan Responsa program (on CD\USB, but not the website) links all pesukim to nearly all of Safrut Chazal: Medrashim, Bavli, Yerushalmi, Tosefta, and more.

Answer (score 0):

I found a refernce to [WebShas](http://webshas.org/) that may be useful. You would have to check what the links and search actually do as I have not tested it.

Using google I found an ad for the [Bar Ilan discs](http://www.jewishsoftware.com/products/Bar_Ilan_Judaic_Library__School__Library_Edition_2649.asp) which says that it includes a concordance. If this is what you have, then it should already be in your system.

> **Bar Ilan Judaic Library School & Library Edition**
>
> Some of the many Features of Bar Ilan's Judaic School Library, you
>   can:
>
> - Powerful Boolean Search Engine – Search by: Word, Phrase, Expression - including Grammar.
> - **Complete interactive Concordance on the Bible and Talmud…**
> - Display Search Results by - long excerpts of text, short excerpts, or just a list of the sources.
> - Display any combination of Database Texts on screen – and see all relevant groups of commentaries.
> - Save your search results and other texts, so you can view them or print them with a word processor.
> - Select portions of Texts to add to your notes and Class Handouts – saves typing!
> - Includes Biographies of hundreds of Rabbis from medieval times to the present.
> - Calculate Gematrias and find Biblical verses or expressions with the equivalent Gematria.
> - Includes Biographical Sketches of the Rabbis in the Mishna & Talmud.
> - Aramaic Hebrew Dictionary.
> - Abbreviation Dictionary.
> - Display biographies of Talmudic Rabbis and information about their teachers and disciples.
> - Display Hebrew-Gregorian calendar Plus Yahrzeit and Bar Mitzvah Calculator.
> - Display Biblical Verses for Names.
> - Encyclopedia of Talmudic Concepts.