# What are all the Mekorot for Matan Torah

Tags: sources-mekorot

I would like to get a complete list of the mekorot for har sinai or matan torah in the Talmud Bavli/Yerushalmi and Tanach where the events at har sinai are discussed even tangentially.  What are they?

So far for the Bavli I have:

Berakhoth 6b, Makoth 23b, Sotah 12b, PesaHim 68b, Shabbat 88a

For the Torah I have: Parshat Bhar, Mishpatim, Yitro and Kedoshim.

Comment: Wow, a down vote.. shocker. Why do I use this site?

Comment: @avi - because for a vote down, you get one up, too ... like I just did :-). Anyway, can you explain what "sources" you mean? Are you referring to where the term "Har Sinai" and "Torah" is used within the Torah? I'm not getting the idea from the Torah sources that you mentioned.

Comment: Yes, Har sinai, or the giving of the Torah/10 commandments.  If it mentions that place/time for any reason, I'd like to know about that source.

Comment: @avi - The Torah list is quite large. Look throughout Devarim, esp. in Va'etchanan and Ekev. Va'etchanan, itself, has a repetition of the 10 commandments. Ekev mentions the giving of the Torah and the Golden Calf. Ki Tavo mentions writing the Torah on gogantic stones. Just some more examples. I think it would be too long to list all the places in the Torah, itself. Perhaps a concordance may assist you?

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to say that all of the Torah references Sinai tangentially, so you might want less of a tangent...

Instead of listing out sources (since as [@DanF mentions](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/38978/what-are-all-the-mekorot-for-matan-torah/38982#comment104327_38978), there are many, and since list answers aren't very interesting), I'd like to point you to some resources on this.  Check out [the Intelligent Index to the Talmud](http://webshas.org/yomtov/shavuos/matan.htm) and [HaMafteach, the Index to the Talmud](http://hamafteach.org/).

For a more classical approach, you can also check out the [Toldot Aharon](http://cf.uba.uva.nl/en/collections/rosenthaliana/menasseh/1889d6-1/index.html) or [Toldot Yaakov](http://cf.uba.uva.nl/en/collections/rosenthaliana/menasseh/1889d6-2/index.html) on the verses in Shemot that you're interested in.  Although I've provided some links to poorly-scanned versions, you can usually find Toldot Aharon in a Mikra'ot Gedolot, and someone with more patience than I may be able to provide better links.

That's Talmud.  As for Tanakh, I'd just use a concordance (like [Strong's](http://www.eliyah.com/lexicon.html)) and look up key words - Sinai, Torah, etc.

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/38398/is-there-a-resource-that-shows-all-uses-of-a-tanach-verse-in-the-talmud