# Talmud citations in order of pasuk

Tags: product-recommendation, talmud-gemara, tanach

Is there any resource, online or otherwise, that lists all of the Talmud's citations of psukim in the order that the psukim appear in Chumash or Tanakh?

Comment: In the back of every Oz veHadar gemara, for that particular masechta....is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @Shokhet http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37970&st=&pgnum=721&hilite=

Comment: Isn't this listed in standard Mikraot Gedolot? See _Toldot Aharon_ http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9597&st=&pgnum=20

Comment: @shoket no that's not what I'm looking for. I want to know by pasuk, not by masechta. So I can look up some particular pasuk and find all the places it's quoted

Comment: @Daniel Oh. You might want to reword your question, then, because at least two other people (besides myself) thought that's what you meant.

Comment: @Daniel is this what you're asking for? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/38398/472

Comment: @MonicaCellio I think so; have voted to close as duplicate.