# Who wrote the Toldos Aharon on Chumash?

Tags: sources-mekorot

Most Chumashim contain a commentary, called Toldos Aharon, which cites which gemara cites each verse (kind of like a reverse Torah Ohr).

Who wrote it?

Comment: Can you link to a page of Humash with such commentary? That may help in the search.

Comment: loosely related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/38398/is-there-a-resource-that-shows-all-uses-of-a-tanach-verse-in-the-talmud

Comment: @Menachem, given the similar name, it seems like אהרן היימאן is a likely source (except that what is in the Chumashim is abridged to only focus on Talmud).

Comment: @Yishai: It was published in 1937-38, so if you can find an earlier Chumash with the Toldot Aharon it will disprove that theory: http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%9F_%D7%94%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%9F

Comment: @Menachem, well then it looks like the name is [coincidental](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=39996&st=&pgnum=16&hilite=)

Comment: @Yishai http://chabadpedia.co.il/index.php/%D7%90%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%94%D7%9D_%D7%93%D7%95%D7%93_%D7%9C%D7%90%D7%95%D7%95%D7%90%D7%95%D7%98

Comment: @ShmuelBrin, looks like you found your answer.

Comment: @Yishai it's un-sourced.

Comment: Here is that Sefer on hebrewbooks.org: http://hebrewbooks.org/45349 - There are 3 separate scans.

Comment: They're pretty tough to read, so here's the other 2: http://hebrewbooks.org/44293 and http://hebrewbooks.org/23999

Comment: Here someone reprinted just the chiddushim from the Sefer Beit Aharon. It might have some biographical information - http://www.otzar.org/wotzar/book.aspx?170550&

Answer (score 4, accepted):

R. Aharon of Pizaro.  Lived in a place called Nikalaro, Italy in the 16th Century.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aaron_of_Pesaro

Comment: some more sources: http://www.encyclopedia.com/article-1G2-2587500042/aaron-pesaro.html

http://www.lincoln.ox.ac.uk/Aron-of-Pesaro

http://people.ucalgary.ca/~elsegal/TalmudMap/MG/MGToledotAharon.html

http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_36619_70.pdf

Apparently one of the editions of the publication Sinai from Mossad HaRav Kook discusses him in detail: http://forum.otzar.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=12247

Comment: Here's the sefer: http://www.otzar.org/wotzar/book.aspx?104155

Comment: Why do you say he lived in Nikalaro, and not Pesaro? Also, I couldn't find a place called Nikalaro, is there a different spelling?

Comment: Just passing on what I found in the Chorev edition of the Chumash.  The town in Italy may now go by a different name.

Comment: It is probably written in Hebrew in the Chumash. Can you add the hebrew spelling to your answer? It may aid in searching.