# Source for sources on Nach

Tags: sources-mekorot

I have an older Nach (Neviim and Kesuvim) with an unhelpful source list, an older Toldos Aharon.

I would like a better source list to cross reference the pesukim to Chazzal, to supplement my Nach so I don't have to replace it.

I am not looking for a search engine to enter words into. I would like a list going passuk by passuk just like the Toldos Aharon.

Online or book form suggestions welcome.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/38398/is-there-a-resource-that-shows-all-uses-of-a-tanach-verse-in-the-talmud

Comment: Thanks. I'll need to check out those suggestions later. But definitely along the right track of what I'm looking for. I don't know why that question didn't show up in my searches.