# Chapters of Tanach present in Talmud Bavli

Tags: number, talmud-gemara, tanach, talmud-bavli, statistics

I heard there is a style of Talmud study somewhere, where as a verse presents itself in the Talmud, the student would learn the entire chapter from תנ״ך.

With that, were one to complete the entire Talmud Bavli, would he also have completed the entire תנ״ך?

Comment: https://blog.sefaria.org/2015/05/18/how-much-of-tanach-is-in-the-talmud/

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/38398/is-there-a-resource-that-shows-all-uses-of-a-tanach-verse-in-the-talmud

Comment: Companion question: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/99871/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From what I can tell off of [Sefaria's Connections visualization](https://www.sefaria.org/explore), by skimming through each Sefer individually and noting the Perakim with no connections, the chapters one will *not* learn with this method are:

- Shemos 37
- Yehoshua 23
- Shmuel I:27, I:29, and II:4
- Melachim II:1 and II:16
- Yeshaya 15
- Yirmiya 20, 35, and 45
- Yechezkel 6, 12, 30, 35, and 42
- Nachum 3
- Zechariah 6
- Tehillim 28, 43, 53, 64, 67, 70, 83, 96, 123, 131, and 143
- Iyov 17 and 23
- Ezra 5
- Nechemiah 3
- Divrei HaYamim I:6, I:10, I:19, I:20, II:8, II:10, II:11, II:12, II:17, and II:34

Overall, that's 43 Perakim. Out of a total of 931 Perakim, that means that, by Perek, 95.38131% of Tanach will have been learned.

The missing Perakim are found among 12 Sefarim (counting the I's and II's together, Nachum and Zechariah among Trei Asar, and Ezra and Nechemiah together). That means that a full half of Tanach by Sefer contains Perakim not cited by Shas Bavli.

Comment: And here I was getting all revved up to do this with a script against mechon mamre's text ...

Comment: @Shalom Feel free to do so; Sefaria's not perfect, and perhaps they missed something/counted something which shouldn't be.

Comment: @Shalom If you're interested in [taking a crack at the Yerushalmi](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/99871/)...

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you are asking regarding the standard (Christian) chapters, there are many chapters that are never cited in the Babylonian Talmud, such as Exodus 37, Joshua 23, Ezra 5, Chronicles I chapter 6, and Chronicles II chapter 8 (see e.g. [here](https://www.sefaria.org/explore)).  That said, he would have covered an overwhelming majority of Tanach.