# Which source shows the Gamorrahs for each pasuk in the Chumash?

Tags: mesorah-tradition

Just the other day in a Shul somebody was trying to tell me about a sefer which for each pasuk in the Chumash gives the places in the Talmud where that pasuk is discussed. I wish I’d paid more attention because that’s exactly what I need right now. Does anybody know which sefer does this?

Comment: Many editions of Mikraot Gedolot contain a work like that called תולדות אהרן see https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14020&st=&pgnum=19 right above שפתי חכמים. Or did you want a dedicated volume?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/38398/is-there-a-resource-that-shows-all-uses-of-a-tanach-verse-in-the-talmud See if any comments or answers in this are it

Comment: Note that Sefaria will do this for you, when you click on a verse and select Talmud in the related texts

Answer (score 4):

The three-volume work תורה הכתובה והמסורה is probably what you're looking for. It's available on Hebrewbooks here: [vol 1](https://hebrewbooks.org/39132), [vol 2](https://hebrewbooks.org/39134), [vol 3](https://hebrewbooks.org/39133). The first volume is all of Torah, and the other two are for Nakh.

Answer (score 3):

The [Torah Temimah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torah_Temimah) is exactly that. It does not necessarily include *every* reference to Gemara, but it includes plenty of them and with a running commentary that helps explain the references and make a lot of interesting connections.

I studied it for many years with a group led by Chaim Fruchter, who now has a weekly podcast of selected items from each week's Parasha [available online](https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/ten-minute-torah-temimah/id1716404693).

Answer (score 2):

Artscroll's mikraos gedolos has an anthology that draws from both Talmuds (j & b) called ליקוטי בבלי וירושלמי https://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781422616086.html , click "view inside" to see